# What tool can I use to backup a mysql database on my desktop?

Tags: mysql

PHPMYAdmin gives me an error each time I try to export.

Here's the error:  Firefox can't find the file at https://ipaddress:8443/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/export.php.

I want to  have a .sql backup of the database stored on my pc in case my site is hacked.

What tools or hacks would help me get around this problem?

Comment: If you're using commercial hosting, you should contact your hosting's support. phpMyAdmin should do fine.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to backup your DB, probably the last of which I would consider to be security. Backing up your database generally presents new attack vectors all by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MySQL Workbench** comes with some utilities for exporting databases. If you have command access to the server (or you have mysql installed in your computer) you can also use **mysqldump**.

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html) covers this topic pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump -u UserName -p Password DataBase | gzip > /mnt/ecBookEximius.sql.gz 
U get a Zip file of UR DB